# Can I run an "explain analyze" on a query using JOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, explain

Can I run `explain analyze` on a query in JOOQ? like:

```
explain analyse select some, columns from some_table
```

but do it using JOOQ on PostgreSQL database?

I have found an interface `org.jooq.Explain`, with a method `DSLContext.explain​(Query query)` - but it seems just to use `EXPLAIN` on a query:

```
@Support({AURORA_MYSQL,AURORA_POSTGRES,H2,HSQLDB,MARIADB,MEMSQL,MYSQL,ORACLE,POSTGRES,SQLITE}) 
Explain explain​(Query query)
Run an EXPLAIN statement in the database to estimate the cardinality of the query.
```

Is there any sensible way to run an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the database from the code side?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run explain. Example

```
SelectWhereStep<ModuldefRecord> where = dsl.selectFrom(MODULDEF);
Explain explain = dsl().explain(where);

System.out.println(explain);
```

The output look like this (for Oracle)

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Plan hash value: 3871168833                                                   |
|                                                                              |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|| Id  | Operation         | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     ||
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
||   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |          | 61303 |    30M|  1305   (1)| 00:00:01 ||
||   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MODULDEF | 61303 |    30M|  1305   (1)| 00:00:01 ||
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Explain also contains rows and cost

```
    /**
     * The number of rows (cardinality) that is estimated to be returned by the query.
     * <p>
     * This returns {@link Double#NaN} if rows could not be estimated.
     */
    double rows();

    /**
     * The cost the database associated with the execution of the query.
     * <p>
     * This returns {@link Double#NaN} if cost could not be retrieved.
     */
    double cost();
```

Comment: The author was looking for explain analyze, not explain. The author is already aware of explain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported yet: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10424. Use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), instead:

```java
ctx.fetch("explain analyze {0}", select);
```

Answer (score 0):

For mariadb I needed to do:

```
SelectConditionStep<TableNameRecord> select =
    context.selectFrom(Tables.TABLE_NAME)
    .where(filter);
System.out.println(context.fetch("analyze " + select.getSQL(ParamType.INLINED)));
```

which produced the output:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+-------+--------+----------+------------------------+
|  id|select_type|table     |type |possible_keys    |key              |key_len|ref   |rows|r_rows |filtered|r_filtered|Extra                   |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+-------+--------+----------+------------------------+
|   1|SIMPLE     |table_name|range|table_column_name|table_column_name|20     |{null}|1000|1000.00|   100.0|     100.0|Using where; Using index|
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+-------+--------+----------+------------------------+
```

If you use `context.explain(select)` as proposed by another answer you lose a few columns:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+------------------------+
|  id|select_type|table     |type |possible_keys    |key              |key_len|ref   |rows|Extra                   |
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+------------------------+
|   1|SIMPLE     |table_name|range|table_column_name|table_column_name|20     |{null}|1000|Using where; Using index|
+----+-----------+----------+-----+-----------------+-----------------+-------+------+----+------------------------+
```